# print a 2D array in C

Tags: python, c, arrays, multidimensional-array

I was wondering if it was possible to print a 2D array in C like it is in python. For example, if I have `int array1[10][10];` then fill in the array then `printf("%li", array1)` does not seem to work. In C, is there something like `printf` that can print `array1` as `[1, 2, 3, 4]`? in python it would just be `print(array1)`

Comment: Your title mentions 2D arrays, yet your example is about 1D arrays. Is that intentional?

Comment: This is a nit, but `[1, 2, 3, 4]` is not how a 2D array would be printed.

Comment: i know. i know. i'm very familiar with python and don't feel like typing out an example that you guys likely already have experience with.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately, there is no standard way to do that. The way to print your array would be:

```
int array1[] = {1, 2, 3, 4};

size_t i = 0;
for (i = 0; i < 4; i++){
    printf("%d ", array1[i]);
}
```

Note that to be more correct, you can get the size of the array using `sizeof`:

```
int array1[] = {1, 2, 3, 4};

int i = 0;
for (i = 0; i < sizeof(array1)/sizeof(int); i++){
    printf("%d ", array1[i]);
}
```

Some people would hold that you should use `size_t` instead of `int` for the index, since that is what `sizeof` returns.

**EDIT:** Python can print the entire array because the array is stored not just as a bunch of numbers in memory, but as a data-structure which stores other information as well, such as the length of the array.

Comment: is there a function anyone wrote that does it in the neatest way possible?

Comment: It's better to avoid array size literals when possible (DRY principle). Instead, `#define NELTS(a) (sizeof(a)/sizeof((a)[0])) // number of array elements` and replace that `4` with `NELTS(array1)`

Answer (score 1):

More specifically, when printing a 2D array in C, you'll need to implement a double for-loop:

//in pseudo code

1. assume array is called myArray
2. get the width of the array, call it j
3. get the length of the array, call it k
4. for(a = 0; a < j; a++){
5. ....for(b = 0; b < k; b++){
6. ........printf("%d", myArray[a][b]);
7. ....}
8. }

Answer (score 0):

The straightforward answer is "no" ... you have to code it yourself. And it isn't possible to write a general dumper routine in C because the size of arrays is not known.

Comment: @tekknolagi "the size of arrays is ... known". That is, the size is stored as an attribute of the array and can be queried. This is true of most modern programming languages.

Comment: oh i see... then is there a basic implementation in C?

Comment: @tekknolagi If you're asking whether arrays with a length attribute could be generally implemented in C ... you could do it for arrays containing a single type, e.g., int, but not generally because C doesn't have reflection, generic types, or similar needed mechanisms. C is primitive, very primitive. If you want such things, try a more modern language like D or Scala.

Answer (score -2):

```
   // Int array [10][10];
for(i=0;i<10;i++)
{
for(j=0;j<10;j++)
{
Print("%d",array[i][j]);
}
}
```

Using this code you can print  2D array in C

Comment: It won't even compile in C.